# Azure Stack On-premise Deployment

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-stack

I cant seem to understand from reading the relevant material in the internet if it is even possible deploying and installing the azure stack deployment kit for on-premise if my environment will; ALWAYS not connected to the internet AT ALL, even at the installation phase?

Comment: That was a fairly simple Google search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-app-service-deploy-offline

Comment: I saw that article but it is talking about installing the App Service in an offline environmet. Im trying to figure out if it is possible to install Azure stack itself without any connection to the internet. EDIT: i know it can be disconnected later, after installation but i wonder if it could be installed in the first place without an internet connection.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it talks to Azure AD during provisioning...

Comment: Installation guide.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/asdk/asdk-install?view=azs-1908

Answer (score 0):

You can install ASDK disconnected, however it is recommended to install connected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/asdk/asdk-install?view=azs-1910

> For best results, even if you want to use a disconnected Azure Stack
>   environment using AD FS as the identity provider, it's best to install
>   the ASDK while connected to the internet. That way, the Windows Server
>   2016 evaluation version included with the ASDK installation can be
>   activated at deployment time.